# How to get VBA hyperlinks working?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I tried to use hyperlinks but it is not doing anything at all. I would like to know what I need to change to use hyperlinks please.

```
Sub RDB_Worksheet_To_PDF()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim PONumber As String
    Dim FolderPath As String

    PONumber = Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Cells(8, 6).Value
    FolderPath = "Z:\1.PRODUCTION\1. PURCHASING\PO H 2012\"

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "There is more then one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
               "be aware that every selected sheet will be published"
    End If

    'Call the function with the correct arguments
    FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(ActiveSheet, FolderPath & PONumber, True, True)

    If FileName <> FolderPath & PONumber Then
        'Ok, you find the PDF where you saved it
        'You can call the mail macro here if you want
        MsgBox "Sweet! The PO has been saved as a PDF." & vbNewLine & _
               "Click on the PO Number in the PO Number WorkSheet to view."
    Else
        MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
               "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
               "There is no PO number selected" & vbNewLine & _
               "The path to Save the file in is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
               "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"
    End If


    Sheets("PO Number").Select
    Range("A1").Select


    Set smvar = Cells.Find(What:=PONumber, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
       If Not smvar Is Nothing Then smvar.Activate

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
            FolderPath & PONumber & ".pdf"
        Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't posted all of your code so we can't know if something in your code is causing this.

Comment: I have posted all of my code. it is all

Comment: It's all not here.  Your second block of code does not appear in the first and the first has no `End Sub` so it cannot be all of the code.

Comment: they are all in one code, I wrote them into two so I can explain my situation better, but I am telling they are all in one code

Comment: Edit your question then. Is the line "This is the hyperlinks..." supposed to be like a comment. It breaks up your code and makes it look like you are talking about 2 portions. Move the comment out of your code or indent it. @DavidZemens I wasnt confident enought that an edit would not deface the post. What you did is what i would have done.

Comment: It is hard to tell what you may have as the `Selection` at the time this statement executes. I suspect that is your problem. It is generally advised to avoid relying on the `Select` and `Activate` methods, for this exact reason: it quickly becomes difficult to know what is selected, activated, etc., and this can cause lots of errors and problems while running code.

Comment: @Matt I made the edit based on OP comments.

Comment: Do you get a hyperlink in cell A1?

Comment: when you say "this is not doing anything" what do you want or expect it to *do*? I am certain it's "doing" something. But it may not be doing what you intend.

Comment: I want to this code to get a hyperlink in cell A

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - adapt to suit.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim shtPO As Worksheet, smvar As Range

    Set shtPO = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set smvar = shtPO.Cells.Find(What:="Hello", _
                 After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not smvar Is Nothing Then
       shtPO.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=smvar, Address:="C:\folder\folder2\file.pdf"
    End If

End Sub
```

No need to select/activate anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the issue very clearly...
But may you should select the sheet first then create the Hyperlink...

```
Sub createHyperLink()

 Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Select

 ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
 Address:="example.pdf", _
 ScreenTip:="This is the link file", _
 TextToDisplay:="Linked PDF"

End Sub
```

This would create the link in the default selected cell in sheet named "Purchase Order with Sales Tax"

Comment: What if I want to create the link in the different sheet? Do I change "Purchase Order with Sales Tax"?